# Can I build application to Scan without EZTwain?

Tags: vb.net

Can I build software to scan document or photo without EZTwain library on VB.NET ?
because Twain library make scan in another window also I can't put multiple choice for the input format...

Answer (score 0):

The most important alternative is the WIA library. (Windows Image Acquisition)

*WIA is a standardized Win32 API for acquiring digital images from devices that are primarily used to capture still images, and for managing these devices.*

You can find an exhaustive article and sample how to use this library at this link [WIA-Scripting-and-NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2303/WIA-Scripting-and-NET)
More on WIA can be found on the MSDN starting from [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630368%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As Steve said, the best alternative is to use the WIA. I know a third party toolkit that could help you doing your requirements which is leadtools. You can check this page for an [Introduction to WIA](http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/dh/wa/leadtools.wia_introduction.html)

Also, you can check this [Tutorial](http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/dh/to/leadtools.topics.wia~wa.topics.wiaacquiringanimage.html)

Comment: You should post some code and an overview, links go dead all the time.